# Trouble with the State Monad

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to write a program to generate 'word chains', e.g. bat -> cat -> cot -> bot, using the list monad (mostly comprehensions) to generate combinations of words, and the state monad to build up the actual chain as i go through the possibilities. That second part is giving me trouble:

```
import Control.Monad.State

type Word = String
type Chain = [Word]

getNext :: Word -> State Chain Word
getNext word = do
  list <- get
  return (list ++ "current word")
```

The part where I generate words works and is given below, but as you can see I don't really know what I'm doing in this part. Basically `wordVariations :: Word -> [Word]` takes a Word and returns a list of Words that differ in one letter from the given word. I'm trying to change this so that each word has a state signifying its predecessors:

For example: input = "cat". the final value is "got", the final state is ["cat","cot","got"]

What I have now will give me "got" from "cat" after 3 steps, but won't tell me how it got there.

None of the State Monad tutorials I found online were terribly helpful. The above code, when compiled with GHC, gives the error:

```
WordChain.hs:42:11:
    Couldn't match type `Word' with `Char'
    When using functional dependencies to combine
      MonadState s (StateT s m),
        arising from the dependency `m -> s'
        in the instance declaration in `Control.Monad.State.Class'
      MonadState [Char] (StateT Chain Data.Functor.Identity.Identity),
        arising from a use of `get' at WordChain.hs:42:11-13
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: list <- get
    In the expression:
      do { list <- get;
           return (list ++ "current word") }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This is just meant to be a test to work off of, but I can't figure it out!

The code in full is below in case it is helpful. I know this may not be the smartest way to do this, but it is a good opportunity to learn about the state monad. I am open to necessary changes in the way the code works also, because I suspect that some major refactoring will be called for:

```
import           Control.Monad.State

type Word  = String
type Dict  = [String]
-- data Chain = Chain [Word] deriving (Show)

replaceAtIndex :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceAtIndex n item ls = a ++ (item:b) where (a, (_:b)) = splitAt n ls

tryLetter str c = [replaceAtIndex n c str | n <- [0..(length str - 1)]]

wordVariations str = tryLetter str  =<< ['a' .. 'z']

testDict :: Dict
testDict = ["cat","cog","cot","dog"]

------- implement state to record chain

type Chain = [Word] -- [cat,cot,got,tot], etc. state var.

startingState = [""] :: Chain

getNext :: Word -> State Chain Word
getNext w = do
  list <- get
  return ( list ++ "current word")
```

Comment: should `getNext` change your state? (where is it changed at all) - the problem is right there - what should this really do? BTW: why do you think you need a state-monad at all here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the error you posted is in this line `return ( list ++ "current word")`.

- `"current word"` type is `Word`, which is an alias for `String, which is an alias for`[Char]`.
- The variable `list` has a type of `Chain`, which is an alias for `[Word]`, which is an alias for `[[Char]]`.
- The type signature of the function forces the return type must be a Word.
- `++` requires that the types on both sides be a list with the same type, `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.
- However, if you plug in the above type signatures, you get the type `[Word] -> [Char] -> [Char]` which has mismatched "a"s.

---

Quick but fairly important performance side note: prepending to a list is much faster then appending, so you might want to consider building them backwards and using (:) and reversing them at the end.

---

The State Monad is not really the right choice for storing the steps used to get to the result. At least it is certainly overkill, when the List Monad would be sufficient to complete the task. Consider:

```
-- given a list of words, find all possible subsequent lists of words
getNext :: [String] -> [[String]]
getNext words@(newest:_) = fmap (:words) (wordVariations newest)

-- lazily construct all chains of every length for every word
wordChains :: String -> [[[String]]]
wordChains word = chain
  where chain = [[word]] : map (>>= getNext) chain

-- all the 5 word long chains starting with the word "bat"
batchains = wordChains "bat" !! 4
```

(Disclaimer: code compiled, but not run).

getNext takes a Chain, and returns a list containing a list of Chains, where each one has a different prepended successor in the chain. Since they share a common tail, this is memory efficient.

In wordChains, by repeatedly mapping using the list monad with (>>= getNext), you end up with a lazy infinite list, where the zeroth item is a Chain the starting word, the first item is all 2 item Chains where the first is the starting word, the second item is all 3 item chains, and so on. If you just want one chain of length 5, you can grab the head of the 4th item, and it will do just enough computation to create that for you, but you can also get all of them.

Also, getNext could be expanded to not repeat words by filtering.

---

Finally, when it comes to finding wordVariations, another algorithm would be to construct a filter which returns True if the lengths of two words are the same and the number of characters that are different between them is exactly 1. Then you could filter over a dictionary, instead of trying every possible letter variation.

Good luck!

Comment: Those lazy infinite lists... One of these days I'll be able to intuit those. Thanks, this works great. I had hoped for this to be a learning experience for the state monad, but I've learned enough other stuff that I think I'll call it a success. Thanks!